# How can i make a tar of selective file type under a directory

Tags: backup, files, tar

I want to take backup of selective files say *.py under a directory.
How can i do that?

Please help me to achieve it.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, you'd probably want something more like

```
tar cvf filename.tar `find . -name '*.py'`
```

The first example would only get *.py files one level deep.

Answer (score 0):

`tar cf filename.tar *.py` Should do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

In order to accommodate possible filenames with spaces and do a recursive search, use:

```
find . -type f -name '*.py' -print0 | tar --null cvf archive_name.tar -T -
```

Comment: You probably want 'cvf' as the filename has to come as the argument to f